# using flyway to patch multiple identical schemas

Tags: flyway

i have thoroughly read the flyway documentation but i am unclear if the scenario i want is possible or not. i need to patch many identical schemas within the same database but i do not know all the schema names at the time when i am writing the sql scripts.

i know about the *schemas* parameter, but the 2 possible strategies mentioned in the [FAQ](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#multiple-schemas) do not apply to my scenario.

the scenario is similar to a university providing schemas for their students:

- i would like to provide sql scripts with no schema prefixes for objects
- every schema should have its own schema_version table
- upon flyway:migrate every schema defined in the *schemas* parameter should be patched separately, i.e. the sql scripts should be run in each schema.

i know that a potential problem is, that 'schema' means something different in f.ex. oracle than in postgres, so i wonder if there is any other recommended way to achieve this.

otherwise i am thinking of implementing this functionality myself...is there a chance to get this feature upstream if we do it on our own?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best chance is to wrap Flyway with a method that will list the applicable schemas, and then make one Flyway run per schema with the schemas property set to the correct one.

This really is a nice feature, so at this time I would say the chances are pretty slim to see it included in the main distro.

Comment: This is what we did, it's definitely a narrow use case. We have a service (called from our app or from a new maven plugin) that queries the database for schema names and loops over them updating the setSchema() on the flyway object and calling migrate() for each.