# Multiple schemas works for clean and init, but not for migrate

Tags: database, migration, flyway

With the command-line option, I tried to do the multiple-schemas thing:  have a gold schema with the metadata table, and a series of user sandboxes slaved to it.

```
flyway -schemas=SCHEMA1,SCHEMA2 clean
```

This worked OK.  All the schemas were wiped.

```
flyway -schemas=SCHEMA1,SCHEMA2 init
```

This worked OK, or at least as I expected:  only created metadata table in the first schema.

```
flyway -schemas=SCHEMA1,SCHEMA2 migrate
```

This did not work - only migrated the first schema, subsequent were ignored.

Is this broken in 2.1.1?  This seems like the basic point of having multiple schemas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flyway - managing multiple schemas doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262280/flyway-managing-multiple-schemas-doesnt-work)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476659/using-flyway-to-patch-multiple-identical-schemas